# Unable to determine IP address from host name when trying to hit external system from salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices

I get the below error when trying to hit the external system

> Unable to determine IP address from host name
>          The dnsserver returned:    Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
>
> The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the
>   URL.    Check if the address is correct.

however,it was working 4 hrs ago..and now when i hit the same url from advanced REST client,it seems to be working fine
What may be the error?

Thanks,

Neha Patil

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, the DNS server that Salesforce uses cannot resolve the domain-name.

DNS-servers can be out of sync, in that it takes a while before all DNS servers are up to date after a DNS setting (i.e. domain -> IP) was changed.

Now, the only thing to check is whether your local DNS server OR the Salesforce DNS server is out of sync. You can check that if you are the owner of the domain.

What you want to do is pinging the server locally, checking what IP address it returns and then verify if that IP address is the actual address that also appears in the DNS settings. You can check the latter DNS settings via a controlpanel at the company that provides the domain for you (given that you have DNS control).